# Touch Listeners for Parent and Child Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-view

I have a `HorizontalScrollView` inside a `ViewPager` , I have disabled the ontouchevent of the view pager, but the problem is horizontal scroll view is disturbed by this. It doesn't work properly, only moves a little.

I just want to understand the touch listeners functionality , `onInterceptTouchEvent` and `touchEvent` of the parent and child view, what is the order their calling if i touch on a child view?

Comment: I'm waiting for a response too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

touchEvent is first be handled by child View , if it doesn't handle it ,which means return false,the parent view will handle it. But onIterceptTouchEvent is before touchEvent.